# Play 2.5.x java - How to call a controller method from another controller?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.5

I have two controllers A and B. I want to call A's create method from B. How do I do that?

```
public class A extends Controller {

    public Result create() {
        ...
    }

}

public class B extends Controller {

    public Result create() {
        // How to call A.create() ??
    }

}
```

Comment: No @Idos, you cant do that. We should not initialise the controllers, framework has to do that.

Moreover, even though we try, we cant pass request params to that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Play 2.5, since DI (Google Guice) is in-built, we can inject the desired controller and call its methods straightaway!

```
public class A extends Controller {

    public Result create(String param) {
        ...
    }

}

public class B extends Controller {

    @Inject
    private A a;

    public Result create() {
        a.create("param");
        // do other stuff and return result
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to define another method to contain your logic and then call that method from your controller's method. something like this:

```
public class SampleController extends Controller{
     @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
     public Result createMessage(){
        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
        return ok(createMessageLogic(json.get("id").asLong()));
    }

    public String createMessageLogic(long id){
        return "the id is " + id;
    }
}
```

This way, you can easily inject your controller in the other controller and call the logic methods. However you can consider having a service layer aside your controller classes which is way cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Just create static method that shares the logic and use it to build the `Result` for both actions it will contain `request()` automatically, simplest sample:

```
public class A extends Controller {

    public Result create(String param) {
        return shared("A role", param);
    }

    public static Result shared(String role, String param) {

        String msg = "Path: " + request().path();

        msg += ", role is: `" + role + "`";

        msg += (param == null)
                ? " and has no param"
                : ", with param: " + param;

        return ok(msg);
    }

}

public class B extends Controller {

    public Result create() {
        return controllers.A.shared("B role", null);
    }

}
```

**About params**

Note that actually the only params that you need to resolve in `A.create(...)` and `B.create(...)` are the route parts (`String param` in the `A` route) or maybe some optional params *hardcoded* in each like `role` in the example.

Other things, like `request`, `session`, `cache`, DB data, etc. may (should) be extracted within the `shared()` method.

TIP: if number of params required to pass to the `shared()` method is large and you do not want to create *monsters* like

```
controllers.A.shared(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "foo");
```

just create `Map<String, Object>` collection and pass all at once OR create dedicated transient model, that holds all values in proper fields. The second option is my favorite also when passing many values to common Twirl's templates.

Comment: Thank you! But, how do I pass the required params to that controller method? I mean, that "create()" method of "A" controller tries to read the data from the request parameters, which might be different since the http call is for "B" controller.

Comment: You can pass anything you want to the shared method :) check my edit.